# Retrieve data using AJAX error 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to retrieve data from a JSON file whose URL is

```
http://35.163.112.218:8080/profiles?account=xxxx&profile=xxxx
```

I try to to access the data using AJAX on my local XAMP server. I am getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://35.163.112.218:8080/profiles?account=xxxx&profile=xxxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I am using .html file please can you suggest me where i should to add 
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
I have convert HTML into index and use this header but no success.Thanks